# Need to Specify source for UDP video stream, what is the syntax?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, udp, igmp

I am trying to add to my IPTV box a m3u list with UDP streams but I have to specify the source IP in order for it to run. With VLC it works with this syntax:

udp://[sourceIP]:2000@[MulticatsIP]:2000

Unfortunately, when added to the .m3u file it doesn't work.

The Host IP (IPTV Box) is on the same subnet as the source IP e.g.

HostIP: 10.70.102.xx
Stream Source IP: 10.70.1.xx
MulticastIP: 239.xx.xx.xx

Does anyone know how to do this or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

`.m3u8` files and UDP streams don't belong together.

- `.m3u8` are playlist files for HLS streaming (chunked straming)
- `UDP streams` are non-chunked